# Symfony ServiceContainer removes service after compile

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I read on the Symfony documentation for the ServiceContainer that any services that are not used before compiling the container are removed from the container.

Now, I compile the container on the request if the container isn't cached.

How would I stop unused services from being removed, especially if they're required after the container has been compiled?

I'm aware Drupal does it by essentially re-writing the the container (mostly code taken from the original Symfony container), but although this is an option I'm wondering if there's a more efficient method on doing this? Also, I'm relatively new to Symfony, so any related documentation links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all unused `private` Symfony services are removed, simply because they are private and they are not defined to be called from outside.

If the `private` service is used only once, it will be inlined (and removed from the container).

But the `public` services are not removed from the container, even if you don't use them, so if you want keep your service in the DI container, make sure that it is public